# Can you append elements that have already been outputted by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is a weird question but can you append/add html to an element that was outputted by jQuery?

So I’ve been trying to add/append some content, another div element, into a menu. The append works everywhere except for one area (where I actually want to place it) to see if I was doing something wrong (I wasn’t). So after investigating, turns out the area where I want to add it is outputted by another jQuery script.

I can always add the code there but since it’s WordPress and it’s a core theme file...it will more than likely get overwritten when ever I upgrade the theme. I also tried to add my script as the very last thing on the footer to give it time. My guess since it’s a dynamic element/menu..the append doesn’t work there since it is. I could be wrong.

I’ve only tried append and prepend...I know there is other methods to add html/content into an element using jQuery but I wanted to ask the community If its even possible and if I should use something else instead of append? Or what would be a better way to add it?

I hope this makes sense.

The code that I used to append:
$( ".av-burger-overlay” ).append( "Test" );

This code appends except in the menu since the menu is dynamically created when you click on burger menu to open the menu.

Comment: Did you know you can create child themes to customize themes without losing changes after updates? -> [Theme Handbook: child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). Also, when asking questions that are related to code it's usually best if you include some actual code so we can help you debug it.

Comment: Yes I know I can do that but this file is not something I can add into my child theme since it’s a core theme file and not something I can overwrite with a child theme as explained by the theme developers. As mentioned  I was using the append method. My actually code is this. $( ".av-burger-overlay" ).append( "<div class=‘servicemenu’>Test</div>" ); this worked every where minus the area I actually wanted to be in since that area is dynamically created when click on the burger menu icon

Comment: Maybe i should try binding it to the action...but is it still possible with dynamic content?

Comment: Should be possible but, again, without seeing some more actual code it's very difficult for us to help. Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little update on this for anyone that stumbles upon this. I was able to append content using Ajax

```
/**** call second menu****/
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "path-to-website/wp-content/themes/idg-child/secondmenu.php", // path to your PHP file
                    dataType:"html",
                    success: function(data)
                {

                    $(data).appendTo(inner_overlay);  //load-into-div is the ID of the DIV where you load the <select>

                } // success
                }); // ajax
```

this worked out great! It's very important to note that in order for any external PHP files to work within wordpress you need to load wordpress like so.

```
<?php
  define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
  require( '../../../wp-load.php' );
   echo '<div class="secondmenu">';
   echo '<h2 class="secondmenyhead">What We Do</h2>';
   wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Services', 'theme_location'=>'services' ) ); 
   echo '</div>';
  ?>
```

happy coding :D